# Excel Conditional Random Number Generation

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, excel-2007

I am trying to generate 52560 random numbers in Excel with the following conditions:

1. Value per random number Between 0 and 3
2. The 52560 random numbers should add up to 52547

I havent made much headway.. any help would be much appreciated..

Comment: SO is not free code service. Kindly share what have you tried so far and what is not working so that other can help you on that.

Comment: Hi, I found the solution myself.. Step 1: Used this function to generate 52560 random numbers with 3 decomal values -> =(RANDBETWEEN(0,3)+(ROUND((RAND()),3)))... Step 2: Normalized by dividing each random number by the sum of the excel generated random numbers and multiplied with 52547(the sum which I want). Thanks @Nelly27281 !

Comment: You may want to answer your own question so that people will know that you have the answer now.

Comment: @Nelly27281 thanks for your feedback. Owe you one! Cheers :)

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution myself..

Step 1: Used this function to generate 52560 random numbers with 3 decomal values -> =(RANDBETWEEN(0,3)+(ROUND((RAND()),3)))...

Step 2: Normalized by dividing each random number by the sum of the excel generated random numbers and multiplied with 52547(the sum which I want).

Cheers!